# Can't link admob with firebase iOS/Android project

Tags: android, ios, firebase, admob, firebase-admob

I have two accounts: "A" and "B":
A is main account that hosts iOS/Android unity mobile game on Firebase.
B is using for admob integrated to iOS/Android mobile game.

I'm getting error when trying to link admob analytics to the Firebase project.

I shared firebase project with B by granting permissions as "owner". So account B currently has all access to Firebase mobile app game.

When I'm trying to link admob with Firebase in "App settings" next error appears:

> *Can't link to this Firebase project. Make sure you have sufficient
>   permissions and try again.*

[image]

How to solve the problem above?

Comment: I also need an answer for this

Comment: Same here, also hit this issue.

Comment: same for me - seems Google issue. I'm almost sure that this is a new option. I was trying this few days ago and there was no such option to link Firebase and admob projects.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you already have the right permissions on the Firebase side, could you please check to see if you have the right permissions on the Google Analytics side?

1) From the Google Analytics home page of the GA Property that is linked to the Firebase project, click Admin in the lower-left corner.

[image: Google Analytics Admin]

2) Click "Property User Management"

3) Add/update users, such that their permissions include "Edit"

Comment: This should be accepted as the answer, thank you for taking the time Zilla. This solved my problem

Comment: Worked for me as well. You're welcome, y'all. https://twitter.com/ArtemR/status/1242555085155995652. Sometimes the right person just has to see the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have to use the same email address that created the Firebase project. Despite what the documentation says, you can't just grant "Owner" to another account. I had the same problem; creating a new Firebase project using the same address in AdMob allowed me to link the two.

In case it's useful, here's the forum I found:
https://support.google.com/admob/thread/12976824?hl=en

> In this case the pub can reach out to the Firebase support -
>   https://firebase.google.com/support?category=troubleshooting&hl=en
>   This may also happen due to the complexity of Firebase. Firebase can
>   only be linked with the first email id that was used to create it. For
>   example if the company has 2 employees and Firebase was created using
>   the id of Emp1 then Emp2 cannot use his email id or company email id
>   to relink Firebase (in the absence of Emp1).

Comment: This does indeed seem to be the current situation, not sure why you're getting downvoted. It's a bug in the Admob/Firebase integration as far as I'm concerned. And Google keeps locking threads, without a resolution.

Comment: also you're literally screwed if you already have an account because their terms and conditions state if you have multiple AdSense accounts they'll terminate them. There's literally no way to get monetized now.