# Can't link Admob with Firebase with multiple accounts

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, admob

I have two accounts: "A" and "B":

"A" is main account that hosts iOS swift mobile application on Firebase.
"B" is used for Admob integration with iOS mobile app.

I'm getting error when trying to link Admob to the Firebase project.

I shared firebase project with "B" by granting permissions as "Firebase Admin". So account "B" currently has all access to Firebase mobile app.

I also did everything in this post by sharing permissions in Google Analytics:
[Can't link admob with firebase iOS/Android project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60792149/cant-link-admob-with-firebase-ios-android-project)

But still getting this error:

> Can't link Firebase project. Please try again.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 5 days of tries the error above has gone. Seems, that the problem was related to poor quantity of ads impressions data. Unfortunetly, Google Firebase didn't mention in documentation.